# Paypal Android SDK payment request & onActivityResult

Tags: android, paypal, sdk

I implemented Paypal integration within our Android App
We could test id in Sandbox and Live
Transactions occurs fine but the method

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
```

is never called

Is some app setting missing in [this](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications) ?

Whole implementation follows [this](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/blob/master/docs/single_payment.md) github sample.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possibilities here:

1. You are calling `startActivity` instead of `startActivityForResult` when you launch PayPal SDK's activity and there is no callback once it closes
2. If you are calling `startActivityForResult`, you are handling the callback in the wrong `onActivityResult`.

To check which activity is handling your callback:

1. In every activity you launch, override `onActivityResult`
2. Put breakpoints in every `onActivityResult` in your project
3. Once PayPal transaction goes through, one of them will get hit

Comment: The activity was defined with  android:noHistory="true" inside AndroidManifest.xml.. after removal of this line the problem was solved !